# How to update a node.js package so package.json is changed too

Tags: node.js, npm

It looks like `npm up [package]` doesn't work. Here is an example that a package doesn't get updated.

In package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "vasync": "^1.6.4"
}
```

Check version:

```
$ npm outdated
vasync  1.6.4   1.6.4   2.1.0  app
```

Trying to update:

```
$ npm up vasync
```

Now check again and the result is the same:

```
$ npm outdated
vasync  1.6.4   1.6.4   2.1.0  app
```

What does `npm update` do actually? How to use it to update both, a package itself and a `package.json` as well?

Comment: you could use [ncu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

Comment: @yellowsir, no, that package doesn't work. I already posted several issues to its GitHub page

Comment: `npm i vasync -S` - update node_modules because (^) symbol and -S flag save updated version in package.json file

Comment: @JitendraKumar, nope, that doesn't work either. Tried it already. With `npm cache clean` as well

Comment: @Green modified this line in line "vasync": "*", then `npm i vasync -S`, and not possible to update major version through command line

Answer (score 0):

```
npm up vasync --save
```

This should work perfectly, if you still get the same result, try verbose mode, example

```
❯ npm update rxjs --save --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.2.1/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'update',
npm verb cli   'rxjs',
npm verb cli   '--save',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@5.5.1
npm info using node@v8.2.1
npm verb npm-session 113475d097da3551
npm verb request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 3:22:03 PM
npm verb request id ac8c2e37f0875abd
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm verb headers { server: 'nginx/1.10.1',
npm verb headers   'content-type': 'application/json',
npm verb headers   'last-modified': 'Tue, 24 Oct 2017 17:52:42 GMT',
npm verb headers   etag: 'W/"59ef7dea-36f8e"',
npm verb headers   'content-encoding': 'gzip',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   'content-length': '14997',
npm verb headers   'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
npm verb headers   date: 'Wed, 25 Oct 2017 09:22:04 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   age: '243',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-bma7027-BMA',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '2',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1508923324.118963,VS0,VE0',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept' }
npm verb outdated not updating rxjs because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

In my case, its saying **not updating rxjs because it's currently at the maximum version that matches its specified semver range**

Answer (score -1):

Try using this command if you want to add the dependency inside package.json:

```
npm update {package.name} --save
```

The parameter --save lets node know that you want to reflect the changes inside your package.json, so when you deploy the project and install the packages it will be considered aswell.

Regards.

Comment: I don't want to **INSTALL** a package. I want to **UPDATE** a package. I know how to install packages.

Comment: Try "npm update --save" instead, it worked for me and updated both repositories and package.json file. And sorry about the misunderstanding :)